# Copying values to properties in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have file1.txt which contains:

```
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
PropertyD
```

I have another file named file2.txt which includes value for those parameters in file1.txt. So, file2.txt has parameters and values as follows:

```
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA
PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
PropertyE=valueforpropertyE
PropertyF=valueforpropertyF
```

The script needs to grab the values from file2.txt for the properties in file1.txt and write it to the file1.txt. Also, if there are no matching values for the properties it should ignore. Please see the below required output of file1.txt should look like:

```
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA
PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
```

Note: Values for PropertyE and PropertyF should be ignored because they are not declared in file1.txt.

Is there any way to check the comments and write to the file1.txt

File1.txt

```
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
####Some Comments##
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
PropertyD
```

The values in file2.txt should write the values for properties after the comments in file1.txt. It shouldn’t check the properties before the comment or shouldn’t write values for it. Output of file1:

```
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
####Some Comments##
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA
PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be solved using `grep -f`:

```
grep -Ff file1.txt file2.txt > _file1.txt && mv _file1.txt file1.txt
```

---

**Update:** After the question has been updated `grep` alone won't solve the problem. You can use following awk:

```
awk -F'=' 'FNR==NR{if (p) a[$0]; else {print; if ($0 ~ /####Some Comments##/) p=1} next}
  $1 in a' file1.txt file2.txt > _file1.txt && mv _file1.txt file1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
####Some Comments##
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA
PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava,
Thanks for your reply,
It shows error //grep: F: No such file or directory// below is my command
#grep -Ff file1.txt file2.txt > file1.txt
Is this command is correct?

Comment: @Rashid with this command you are overwriting the `file1.txt`. You need to use a temporary file --> `grep ... f1 f2 > f3 && mv f3 f1`.

Comment: Hi Anubhava,
The file1.txt have some comments it should only write the values for the parameters after the comments. \It should ignore the properties before the comments. Please see the question I have modified it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Anubhava. Is there any ways to hardcore the comment. If the file has many comments it will have issues, it should check only specific comments like ####Some Comments##. How can we hardcore the comment?

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I solved this issue and your code is working fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I just updated the answer by hardcoding `####Some Comments##` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can `source` the file2 and then loop file1 assigning the values of those variables via [indirect variable expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
(
  source f2; 
  while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%s=%s\n" "$line" "${!line}"; done <f1 
) > f3
```

I am doing this within `( )` so it is done in a sub-shell and, hence, the sourced values do not affect what I have in my current session.

So now `f3` contains:

```
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA
PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
```

Note by the way that sourcing a file can be dangerous because it can run things that you don't want.